# WinForms Combox - Adding item to a databound list and then setting that to be the selecteditem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have this:

```
cmbConnections.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbConnections.ValueMember = "Index";
cmbConnections.DataSource = DBConnectionSettings.ConnectionList;
```

All Ok!

Now add new item to list:

```
DBConnectionSettings.Connection c = new DBConnectionSettings.Connection();
c.Name = reply;
c.Index = DBConnectionSettings.ConnectionList.Count + 1;
DBConnectionSettings.ConnectionList.Add(c);
```

I now want to show this new item in the comboxbox as the selected item. Setting the text of the combobox fails.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing Count + 1, I thought Count would be 1 base at least so if anything it'd be Count -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) between your DataSource and the ComboBox.  After you've added your new item, call myBindingSource.ResetBindings(false); and then you will either set the Position property of myBindingSource or the SelectedValue property of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the ValueMember of your combobox to "Index", which means you can select a value in the combobox by setting ComboBox.SelectedValue to the index of your item.  I.e.:

```
cmbConnections.SelectedValue = c.Index;
```

Comment: That throws an exception, cannot set SelectedValue to 0